# How Can I Create an Oauth Signature and SAML Assertion For Intuit Partner Platform?

Tags: php, oauth, saml, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to connect to the Intuit Partner Platform to use the new AggCat API but I am struggling to get the Oauth Signature and SAML assertion setup to authenticate and use the API.  I have looked at the [PHP DevKit for QuickBooks](https://code.intuit.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.php_devkit/wiki/HomePage) as an example but I think that is a different authentication process anyway.  Are there any examples of how to use PHP to authenticate and use the Intuit AggCat API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a PHP sample available on github, but I still have not been able to figure out how to get the SimpleSAMLPHP setup working.  Here is a link to the sample on github: [phpaggcat](https://github.com/pleslie/phpaggcat).

If anyone has more luck with the github sample using SimpleSAMLPHP and can generate a more complete answer, I would appreciate any tips on making it work.

Edit 08/04/2013

I looked at this again recently and got it working.  [See my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049382/1203475)

Answer (score 4):

Currently the only samples are for .Net, Java and Ruby.

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/index.php?title=0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0020_Aggregation_%26_Categorization_Apps/0010_GettingStarted/0027_Call_the_Agg_%26_Cat_APIs

William