# aggcat php sample is not working

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I'm using the following configuration:
Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.4.17

When performing php sample I recieve the following error messages:

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Intuit_Original\class.aggcatauth.php on line 199
**$ResponseKVPairs[$OneKVPair[0]] = $OneKVPair[1];**

Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Intuit_Original\class.aggcatauth.php on line 202
**$oauth_token = $ResponseKVPairs['oauth_token'];**

Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Intuit_Original\class.aggcatauth.php on line 203
**$oauth_token_secret = $ResponseKVPairs['oauth_token_secret'];**

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Intuit_Original\example.php on line 65
**foreach($xmlObj as $OneInstitution)**

I assume the reason is empty tokens recieved (I checked this) from **https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token_by_saml**

My Config.php:

```
<?php

define('SIMPLESAML_PATH',  'C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/phplibs/simplesamlphp-1.11.0');
define('SIMPLEOAUTH_PATH',  'C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/phplibs');

define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY',   'qyprdM8VUKLwmWSytg83gPmnRSGLWJ');
define('OAUTH_SHARED_SECRET',  'yWdb7SHKubxEKxxFnkliGfDAKnehuwh9fkRmfAYk');

define('SAML_IDENTITY_PROVIDER_ID',  'accountingsuite.12359.cc.dev-intuit.ipp.prod');
define('SAML_X509_CERT_PATH',        'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Intuit keys\intuit.crt');
define('SAML_X509_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Intuit keys\intuit.key');
define('SAML_NAME_ID',               '001');  // Up to you; just "keep track" of what you use

define('OAUTH_SAML_URL', 'https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token_by_saml');
define('FINANCIAL_FEED_HOST', 'financialdatafeed.platform.intuit.com');
define('FINANCIAL_FEED_URL', 'https://'.FINANCIAL_FEED_HOST.'/');

require_once(SIMPLESAML_PATH . "/lib/xmlseclibs.php");
require_once(SIMPLESAML_PATH . "/lib/SimpleSAML/Utilities.php");
require_once(SIMPLEOAUTH_PATH . "/OAuthSimple.php");
```

Keys provided work great with C# example. (But I used p12 file).

So why it's not working? Looking forward for your answer.

Comment: Can you please try to use 'isset' to check if $ResponseKVPairs['oauth_token'] is already set.
isset($ResponseKVPairs['oauth_token'])

Please let me know if it removes this notice.

Comment: Used Isset. It fixed Notices, but it didn't fix the situation. Tokens are not recieved. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Intuit_Original\example.php on line 65  foreach($xmlObj as $OneInstitution) The result is empty.

Comment: If possible plz share the code of example.php file. You can verify the .crt and .p12 files using apiexplorer https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest Also check if the following steps are getting executed in SAML[though it is a ref frm java devkit.. but steps are same ] https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits/0275_java_cad_devkit_1.0/0010_authorization#Define_SAML_Settings_in_the_Configuration_File#Step_1:_Create_the_OAuthAuthorizer_Object 
One last advise :) 
Plz ensure that php devkit is able to point to your pvt key file(p12/jks)

Comment: For the supplied example (https://github.com/pleslie/phpaggcat/), as I understand, I can't provide the password for p12 file, so I define the path to crt file. define('SAML_X509_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\Intuit keys\intuit.key'); Is this correct?

Comment: .p12 file works in apiexplorer, but in this sample (config.php) I can't use it, because there is no field for the password.

Comment: It looks correct but I don't know how it works in php devkit. Sorry for that.I used java devkit and configured all values(including pwd and alias) in a config file[intuit-aggcat-config.xml].

Comment: @Alex did you ever figure this out?  I am getting the same error messages and I'm not sure how to resolve them.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble getting the PHP sample app up and working originally.  After some debugging, here are the things I had to change to get it working:

•  The OAuthSimple.php file was not part of the SimpleSAML package that I downloaded as instructed in the [phpaggcat example](https://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple/).  I found the OAuthSimple.php file here: [OAuthSimple.php download](https://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple/tree/master/php).

•  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Changed from true to false in class.aggcatauth.php

•  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Added this line in example.php curl options

•  set_time_limit(120); // Added this at beginning of example.php because bank downloads were taking longer than the default of 30 seconds

•  changed max_input_vars = 2500 in php.ini

Once I made those changes, I was able to connect with the API and get it working.