# Sending a SAML Assertion to the Intuit OAuth Server

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Recently I researched a PHP Sample (PHP Sample App and Authentication Example) but I still can't make it work. *[aggcat php sample is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649847/aggcat-php-sample-is-not-working)*

Did anybody test this sample? Should I use the .crt file for 'SAML_X509_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH' or .p12 file? In case of using .p12 file where I could pass the password?

What other samples (open-source) would you recommend (that can be used to implement my own procedures for retrieving OAuth access token and OAuth access token secret)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the sample app from:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits

I've used the dotnet sample and pass the values for .p12 file private key path and password in the config. You should have something similar in PHP.

Comment: I've tried dotnet sample. But the dotnet libraries are binaries. I'm looking for an open-source implementation of SAML preparation and signing.

Comment: Please try the github link for php: https://github.com/pleslie/phpaggcat/  Edit:I see that you already tried it. Can you see the dotnet sample and see how they pass the password and try implementing something similar in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using the standard options defined in the config.php file.  I did have to modify a few things to get it up and working though.  [See my answer to your other question for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18049382/1203475)